# Storing python list of tuples in a redis sorted set where second element of tuple is used as score

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I have a Python list of tuples like so:

```
lst = [(22, -150.0), (23, -150.0), (18, -148.5), (15, -99.4), (5, -75.75), (4, -49.2), (13, -49.0), (9, -41.3), (20, -25.5), (17, -22.3), (10, -13.1), (16, -12.5), (14, -9.8), (3, -8.5), (1, -8.4), (12, -1.5), (7, -0.6), (2, -0.4), (6, 1.7), (21, 2.7)]
```

How do I pass that into a redis sorted set, such that the second value in each tuple is used as the score? I tried `zadd(sorted_set, *lst)`, but I'm getting the error `value is not a valid float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zadd` method of `redis.StrictRedis` expects arguments in the form of

```
zadd(key, score1, name1, score2, name2, ...)
```

In other words, you need to reverse and unpack the inner tuples as well:

```
In [6]: r = redis.StrictRedis(...)

In [8]: r.zadd('sset', *(y for x in lst for y in x[::-1]))
Out[8]: 20
```

---

`Redis.zadd` and `StrictRedis.zadd` behave differently -- see [README](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) for more details. So if you use `redis.Redis` instead of `redis.StrictRedis` (you shouldn't), do *not* reverse tuples:

```
r.zadd('sset', *(y for x in lst for y in x))
```